# VBA Selenium - Element Not Interactable with Chrome Page

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to interact with an element that has no inspect tab when you right click in Google Chrome? I am trying to create an automation that will log in to a page and paste the Username and password but Selenium won't interact with the Chrome Page. I get a pop window with a username and password but I can't interact with the Chrome page. I tried to use VBA logic like "SendKeys", "Keys.Tab" and "Keys.Enter" but they don't work. Please review my code below:

```
    Driver.SendKeys (pUsername)
    Driver.Wait (WaitShort)
    
    Driver.SendKeys (keys.Tab)
    Driver.Wait (WaitShort)

    Driver.SendKeys (pPassword)
    Driver.Wait (WaitShort)

    Driver.SendKeys (keys.Tab)
    Driver.Wait (WaitShort)

    Driver.SendKeys (keys.Enter)
```

Please help me!

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: If there's a field showing, it's in the html doc and it has an XPath. Did you try XPath extensions like Chropath? It's for chrome but it's just to find the html doc location.

Comment: I installed Chropath on my chrome browser but it still doesn't identify with a XPath. I need to figure out a strategy that will interact with the page without an XPath because this first thing it will do it go to the username box. I need to figure out a way to paste in a value in the username box without an element included. Then from there it will click tab button to the Password field and tab again and sign in by clicking enter. If you know anything please help me out. Thanks